# Angular6 dynamic loading by visibility?

Tags: webpack, angular5, code-splitting

I am trying to split angular5 application to minimize the initial payload size and one of things I consider is splitting the application bundle by components. I have seen the example splitting bundle and lazyload by route but is it possible to lazy-load when components show up in the visiable area?

Answer (score 0):

you can put your  on your visible area, then lazy-load components inside it dinamically. In this way you load your components async

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify clear enough. I want to bundle each component separately then load necessary bundles as those components come into the visible area. I was wondering if the webpack supports this.